# How to add items from a textbox to an array? C#

Tags: arrays, textbox

I want to add items from 13 textboxes to the 13 elements of an array.  All at one time using a button.  How would I go about that?

```
    List<double> scoreArray = new List<double>();
        TextBox[] textBoxes = { week1Box, week2Box, week3Box, week4Box, week5Box, week6Box, week7Box, week8Box, week9Box, week10Box, week11Box, week12Box, week13Box };
            for (int i = 0; i < textBoxes.Length; i++)
        {
         scoreArray.Add(Convert.ToDouble(textBoxes[i].Text));
        }
```

Comment: Make an array of the textboxes then iterate through that array when the button is pressed, saving each string in the array.

Comment: Sorry for the formatting, I'm a noob

Comment: Yes, the code you posted seems good. Just put that in the click event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Put an event handler on the button's Click event.

In the handler, extract the textbox values and set them into the values of the array.

Easy peasy!